# how can i know what is my chrome version using ruby and selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, google-chrome

I have an Api to update my ChromeDriver, then Chrome inside selenium. I need to compare the Chrome version with the ChromeDriver version and if Chrome is updated then update the ChromeDriver.

How do I use Ruby to check the version of these?

Comment: there should be a folder who's name is the version number.  On my machine it's in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

Comment: okey, and how can i read this number whit ruby?????

Comment: Read my answer!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use selenium you will need to specify the path to your chrome application
create a new driver (it will launch a new browser) get the version then quit the new browser

```rb
Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = PATH_OF_YOUR_CHROME
driver = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Driver.new
driver.capabilities.browser_version 
driver.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy with the gem `webdrivers` but before that my advice is to use WATIR instead of selenium ruby directly. WATIR is the nice wrapper for Ruby Selenium Binding. Here is the code, you have to use and it would automatically finds your Chrome version and update the driver accordingly.

```
require 'webdrivers'
require 'watir'
Webdrivers.install_dir = 'C:/Ruby27/bin' #Here is where you have to specify the path in which your chrome driver has to be installed.
Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

oh, *from ruby*, you can get chrome version via system command if you know path of binaries (or find the path with *which*)

```ruby
chrome_version_string = `/path/to/chrome/google-chrome -version`.chomp
```

Similarly you can check chromedriver version

```ruby
chromedriver_version_string = `/path/to/driver/chromedriver --version`.chomp
```

Then you can extract version number/integer from strings, and compare them with api versions or do updating